# switfmailer send in date

Tags: php, symfony

Can you send an email with SwiftMailer on a particular date?

I have a database where I keep the birthdays of clients and would like to send them a greeting.

Comment: It's not built in, you'd have to call the PHP script every day. For that, look into cron jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [console command](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/console/console_command.html) that fetches from the database users that have a birthday today, iterate over the result set and send an email to each of them. Then setup cron to call this command once a day.